# How to simulate <BR> or \n in a JAVA component

Tags: java, html

I have a problem with a component JAVA that is used in a HTML object.

In JAVA I did so:

```
query.append(rs.getString("VALUE")+" \n"); 
while(rs.next())
{
     query.append(rs.getString("VALUE")+" \n");
}
```

I try also this:

```
query.append(rs.getString("VALUE")+" <br>"); 
    while(rs.next())
    {
         query.append(rs.getString("VALUE")+" <br>");
    }
```

And also with `<br/>` or `<br\>` or `/n`.

I extract some value from a database and then I try to concatenate with a character that made the text in more lines.

In HTML I have this situation:

```
<a href="URL">Text Text</a>
```

I want the 2 field "Text" wrapped (in 2 different lines).

If I do inspect element I have this situation:

```
<a href="URL">Text
Text</a>
```

The character `\n` disappeared but the text is in the same line.
If I use `<br>` the text is in the same line with the character `<br>` as string.

How can I have the 2 "Text" in 2 differents lines?

Thanks

Comment: try something like this `<a href="URL"><p>Test</p> <p>Test</p></a>`

Comment: Java is not able to recognise html tag in this case. I don't Know why